# NativeScript ActionBar keeps re-appearing on navigation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a page with a hidden ActionBar (see below) which works fine normally. However when I navigate to another page and then use back() to get back, the ActionBar is now fully visible.

(Note: I require the ActionBar to be on the page so I can change the status bar colour)

This is for the current version of NativeScript Angular.

```
<ActionBar visibility="collapsed"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="*, auto" columns="*" *ngIf="pageLoaded">
...
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Try binding the visibility attribute (`[visibility]="'collapsed'"`), if still doesn't work please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I fixed it by just making it collapsed on the inner page instead of hidden. Not the "right" way to do it, but it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to just remove the ActionBar and find a different way to change the text colour on the StatusBar, that doesn't require the ActionBar on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the Page class to your constructor and call this.page.actionBarHidden = true; in your ngOnInit.

This way you can also remove actionbar you have defined in your html template.

Comment: That wouldn't work because I require it on the page so I can change the StatusBar styling. However, I've found a different way to change the StatusBar now, so all the bars are hidden again.